# After creating a local environment and confirming in Conda list I still get "No module named chainer" error.

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I promise I've looked at suggestions for similiar problems but nothing has worked and I have no idea what to do.

Here are my exact steps. I've got Anaconda installed fine and have used it with other libraries and environments like tensorflow, now I'm just trying to use this one package called "chainer". The only windows version I could find was here:
https://anaconda.org/steerapi/chainer

So I went through these steps:

```
conda create -n p27 python=2.7
activate p27
```

At this point it was clear I was now in the p27 environment, then I did...

```
conda install -c steerapi chainer=0
conda list
```

Then to be safe, while still in the environment I did conda install ipython and conda install jupyter, because I had heard that if these are not installed in the local environment the dependencies might not work when you try to use either of them. I confirmed again with conda list outputting:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\MrMoxie\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py27:
#
backports                 1.0                      py27_0
backports_abc             0.5                      py27_0
bleach                    1.5.0                    py27_0
chainer                   0                        py27_0    steerapi
colorama                  0.3.7                    py27_0
configparser              3.5.0                    py27_0
decorator                 4.0.11                   py27_0
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py27_1
enum34                    1.1.6                    py27_0
filelock                  2.0.4                    py27_0    steerapi
functools32               3.2.3.2                  py27_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py27_0
html5lib                  0.999                    py27_0
ipykernel                 4.5.2                    py27_0
ipython                   5.3.0                    py27_0
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py27_0
jinja2                    2.9.5                    py27_0
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py27_0
jupyter_client            5.0.0                    py27_0
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py27_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py27_2
mistune                   0.7.3                    py27_0
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0
nbconvert                 5.1.1                    py27_0
nbformat                  4.3.0                    py27_0
notebook                  4.3.1                    py27_1
numpy                     1.12.0                   py27_0
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py27_0
path.py                   10.1                     py27_0
pathlib2                  2.2.0                    py27_0
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py27_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py27_1
prompt_toolkit            1.0.9                    py27_0
protobuf                  3.0.0a3                  py27_1    steerapi
pygments                  2.2.0                    py27_0
python                    2.7.13                        0
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py27_0
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py27_0
scandir                   1.5                      py27_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py27_1
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_1
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py27_0
six                       1.10.0                   py27_0
ssl_match_hostname        3.4.0.2                  py27_1
testpath                  0.3                      py27_0
tornado                   4.4.2                    py27_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py27_0
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.5054               0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py27_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py27_0
```

Yet even after all that every time in both ipython and in the jupyter notebook (where I prefer to do the coding/testing work) I get:

```
import chainer
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9758b185b742> in <module>()
----> 1 import chainer

ImportError: No module named chainer
```

Please help, I've googled as much as I can google and tried every idea I can think of, why why why doesn't it recognize a package installed in this environment as being there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the modules you installed in this environment are only recognizable by the python kernel installed in the same environment. You need to add the environment as a kernel in jupyter, and then use that kernel in Jupyter notebook to correctly read and import all modules installed in that environment. The easiest way to do this is using *ipykernel*

After activating the environment, install ipykernel using conda as

```
conda install ipykernel
```

You can then create a kernel with the desired python version installed in your environment using -

```
/path/to/env/bin/python(version) --name "name-of-kernel" --display-name "Display Name of Kernel" --user(or for whoever you want the kernel to be accessible)*
```

You can view your Jupyter kernels using

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

After this, just select this kernel from jupyter notebook and you are good to go.